# Make an opaque IEnumerable query Parallel (PLINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

In a function, I would like to do a parallel processing of IEnumerable that is provided as an argument.

This IEnumerable is already a result of some chaining i.e.:

```
IEnumerable argument = InitialEnumerable.Select(x => DoHeavyProcessing(x))...
```

But to me it's opaque - I can't modify how this argument is created. I don't ad hoc know how it is constructed.

Now, when I call argument.AsParallel() it does no good - AsParallel() only parallelizes processing that is on the right-side of it, but all the work before is run sequentially.

Instead, I need to somehow parse this IEnumerable and "decorate" it so that heavy work is parallelized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  `IEnumerable` is specifically designed in such a way that you cannot fetch a given item until you have already fetched the item before it.

Whatever is generating the `IEnumerable` needs to be the one to provide some type of support for parallelizing the generation of these items.

Comment: Thanks - so I guess the best way to do it would be to make my function have a signature like: function(ParallelQuery<T> data) so that user knows he has to put AsParallel() somewhere to make use of it

Comment: @AdamDabrowski It could still accept a signature of type `IEnumerable`, so long as the caller still uses something like `AsParallel` or similar before their `Select` that does an expensive projection.  Having your method accept an `IEnumerable` simply means that any further operations you perform will be serialized.  Of course, if you accept a `ParallelQuery` the primary thing that you're doing is sending a signal to the caller that they should be parallelizing your query.  If you want to do that, then by all means do that.  If most callers won't need to parallelize their query though...

Comment: I am aware that I can retain a more general signature (or check argument/cast it later) - in my case sequential queries will be processed in a different way then parallel ones (parallel are producers-consumer model with SQLBulkCopy consuming in a single thread). I would like for the user to have a hint from the interface. Thank you for a great response, Servy!